# Unable to deploy aws-load-balancer-controller on Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am trying to deploy the aws-load-balancer-controller on my Kubernetes cluster on AWS = by following the steps given in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html

After the yaml file is applied and while trying to check the status of the deployment , I get :

```
$ kubectl get deployment -n kube-system aws-load-balancer-controller
NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
aws-load-balancer-controller   0/1     1            0           6m39s
```

I tried to debug it and I got this :

```
$ kubectl logs -n kube-system   deployment.apps/aws-load-balancer-controller
{"level":"info","logger":"controller-runtime.metrics","msg":"metrics server is starting to listen","addr":":8080"}
{"level":"error","logger":"setup","msg":"unable to create controller","controller":"Ingress","error":"the server could not find the requested resource"}
```

The yaml file is pulled directly from https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/releases/download/v2.3.0/v2_3_0_full.yaml and apart from changing the Kubernetes cluster name, no other modifications are done.

Please let me know if I am missing some step in the configuration.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you prepare node group with instances enough for pods? (In the doc, just written as an existing cluster.)

Comment: @shimo, I have a running cluster with 1 master and 2 worker nodes.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure if this helps, but for me the issue was that the version of the aws-load-balancer-controller was not compatible with the version of Kubernetes.

- aws-load-balancer-controller = v2.3.1
- Kubernetes/EKS = 1.22

Github issue for more information:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2495

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but the issue was resolved.
Turns out it was due to the ingress controller not being setup properly which caused the issue.

Comment: what was your issue
i am getting the same error

Comment: @AhmedAl-Haffar My issue was that the tags for the public subnet were not setup.
It was set like mentioned below following the documentation and it was resolved.
Key – kubernetes.io/role/elb
Value – 1

Comment: This was my issue. I had to update it by running `helm repo remove eks` and then `helm repo add eks https://aws.github.io/eks-charts`.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed by [Gearheads' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72119216/7126793), issues of this type occur mostly due to version mismatches i.e. EKS version and AWS Load Balancer Controller version.

The good news, however, is that for almost all practical cases the AWS Load Balancer Controller comes with backward compatibility and thus installing the latest version as explained in this [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) should solve the issue as it did for me!